# How to view data in database on fragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to view data in database on fragment and I use TableRow to view data.

**my code Setting database** :

```
public class SqliteManager extends Activity {

public static final int VERSI_DATABASE= 1;
public static final String NAMA_DATABASE = "dbCrudSqlite";
public static final String NAMA_TABEL = "tbAgenda";

public static final String FIELD_ID = "_id";
public static final int POSISI_ID = 0;
public static final String FIELD_JUDUL = "judul";
public static final int POSISI_JUDUL = 1;
 public static final String FIELD_DESKRIPSI = "deskripsi";
 public static final int POSISI_DESKRIPSI = 2;
 public static final String FIELD_WAKTU = "waktu";
public static final int POSISI_WAKTU = 3;

public static final String[] FIELD_TABEL ={ SqliteManager.FIELD_ID, SqliteManager.FIELD_JUDUL, SqliteManager.FIELD_DESKRIPSI, SqliteManager.FIELD_WAKTU };

 private Context crudContext;
 private SQLiteDatabase crudDatabase;
private SqliteManagerHelper crudHelper;

private static class SqliteManagerHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String BUAT_TABEL =
        "create table " + NAMA_TABEL + " (" +
        SqliteManager.FIELD_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        SqliteManager.FIELD_JUDUL + " text not null, " +
        SqliteManager.FIELD_DESKRIPSI + " text not null," +
        SqliteManager.FIELD_WAKTU + " text not null " +
        ");";

    public SqliteManagerHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, NAMA_DATABASE, null, VERSI_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(BUAT_TABEL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

}


public void generateData(SQLiteDatabase database){
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(FIELD_ID, "3");
    cv.put(FIELD_JUDUL, "Abang");
    cv.put(FIELD_DESKRIPSI, "Abang");
    cv.put(FIELD_WAKTU, "Merah");
    database.insert(NAMA_TABEL,null,cv);

    cv.put(FIELD_ID, "2");
    cv.put(FIELD_JUDUL, "Opo");
    cv.put(FIELD_DESKRIPSI, "Opo");
    cv.put(FIELD_WAKTU, "Apa");
    database.insert(NAMA_TABEL,null,cv);
}

public SqliteManager(Context context) {
    crudContext = context;
}

public void bukaKoneksi() throws SQLException {
    crudHelper = new SqliteManagerHelper(crudContext);
    crudDatabase = crudHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    generateData(crudDatabase);
}

public void tutupKoneksi() {
    crudHelper.close();
    crudHelper = null;
    crudDatabase = null;
}

public long insertData(ContentValues values) {
    return crudDatabase.insert(NAMA_TABEL, null, values);
}

public boolean updateData(long rowId, ContentValues values) {
    return crudDatabase.update(NAMA_TABEL, values,
            SqliteManager.FIELD_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public boolean hapusData(long rowId) {
    return crudDatabase.delete(NAMA_TABEL,
            SqliteManager.FIELD_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor bacaData() {
    return crudDatabase.query(NAMA_TABEL,FIELD_TABEL,null, null, null, null,SqliteManager.FIELD_JUDUL + " DESC");
}

public Cursor bacaDataTerseleksi(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = crudDatabase.query(true, NAMA_TABEL,FIELD_TABEL,FIELD_ID + "=" + rowId,null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}

public ContentValues ambilData(String tempat, String lat, String lng) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SqliteManager.FIELD_JUDUL, tempat);
    values.put(SqliteManager.FIELD_DESKRIPSI, lat);
    values.put(SqliteManager.FIELD_WAKTU, lng);
    return values;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> ambilSemuaBaris(){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    Cursor cur;
    try
    {
        cur = crudDatabase.query(NAMA_TABEL, new String[]{FIELD_ID,FIELD_JUDUL,FIELD_DESKRIPSI}, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (!cur.isAfterLast())
        {
            do {
                ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                dataList.add(cur.getLong(0));
                dataList.add(cur.getString(1));
                dataList.add(cur.getString(2));
                dataArray.add(dataList);
            }while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("DB ERROR",e.toString());
    }
    return dataArray;
}
}
```

I want to view data on fragment:

```
public class JawaIndo extends Fragment {
private SqliteManager sqliteDB;
private Activity activity;
TextView bhsjawa,bhsindo;
Button addBtn;
TableLayout tabel4data;

public JawaIndo(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jawaindo, container, false);
    sqliteDB = new SqliteManager(getActivity());
    sqliteDB.bukaKoneksi();

    activity = new Activity();

    tabel4data = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
    bhsjawa = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
    bhsindo = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
    updateTable();

    return rootView;
}

protected void updateTable() {
    while (tabel4data.getChildCount()>1){
        tabel4data.removeViewAt(1);
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = sqliteDB.ambilSemuaBaris();
    for (int posisi = 0; posisi < data.size(); posisi++) {
        TableRow tabelBaris = new TableRow(getActivity());
        ArrayList<Object> baris = data.get(posisi);

        TextView idTxt = new TextView(getActivity());
        idTxt.setText(baris.get(0).toString());
        tabelBaris.addView(idTxt);

        TextView namaTxt = new TextView(getActivity());
        namaTxt.setText(baris.get(1).toString());
        tabelBaris.addView(namaTxt); 

        TextView hobiTxt = new TextView(getActivity());
        hobiTxt.setText(baris.get(2).toString());
        tabelBaris.addView(hobiTxt);
        tabel4data.addView(tabelBaris);
    }
}
}
```

Error when I write this code on class JawaIndo :

```
    activity = new Activity();
    tabel4data = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
    bhsjawa = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
    bhsindo = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
    updateTable();
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post logcat.

Answer (score 1):

You have just change some in your ***onCreateView(***) method:

And it should be

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jawaindo, container, false);
  sqliteDB = new SqliteManager(getActivity());
  sqliteDB.bukaKoneksi();

  //activity = new Activity();

  // Update Here
  tabel4data = (TableLayout) rootView .findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
  bhsjawa = (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
  bhsindo = (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
  updateTable();

  return rootView;
}
```

In this passed your View's object named ***rootView***  as referenced to find the id of your UI element.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read all the code, just the snippet you highlighted and the logcat and even there spotted multiple problems:

- The constraint failed comes when you're trying to call `generateData()` from `onCreateView()`. When running the code again, the very same data is re-inserted, causing the constraint failed failure.
- Then, in here:

  ```
  activity = new Activity();
  tabel4data = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
  bhsjawa = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
  bhsindo = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
  updateTable();
  ```

  You should never instantiate activities with `new`. Now all those `findViewById()`s will return `null` and get you a `NullPointerException` later on in `updateTable()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, my application is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get reference of your from your activity instance. It will always get from the `View` only. The `View` class is responsible to initialize and find the views in your screen. So always find your views by layout only.

Here is your code:

```
activity = new Activity();
tabel4data = (TableLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
bhsjawa = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
bhsindo = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
updateTable();
```

Change it as below. Change your reference of `activity` to `rootView`

```
  activity = new Activity();  
  tabel4data = (TableLayout) rootView .findViewById(R.id.tabel_data);
  bhsjawa = (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.nama_id);
  bhsindo = (TextView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.hobi_id);
  updateTable();
```